# Lookup field not updating when the document uploading

Tags: document-library, lookup-column, document, file-upload

I am uploading document programically and passing lookup field value but its not get updated, how to handle this?

Comment: Providing code might help isolate your problem

Answer (score 1):

For a lookup column you must provide the ID of the item you are referring to.

Thus if the item being lookup has an ID of `3` you must provide that in the hashtable, with lookups to multiple items you must provide the ID and the value separeted by `;#` e.g.: `1;#First Item;#3;#THirdItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You need have to update the SPList object...

Comment: it's not working buddy.